Convolutional Network not Fully Learning MNIST (60% accuracy)
I have been working on a self-made Conv Net for some time. In addition to my network taking multiple epochs to increase the test-set accuracy, the accuracy flatlines at about 60% around 30 Epochs.

The following is the network architecture
input (3x28x28) -> Conv Layer (34x3x3x3) (valid convolution) -> Average Pooling (pooling size=2) -> ReLu -> Flatten -> Linear Layer (100 Nodes) -> ReLu -> Linear Layer (10 nodes) -> softmax -> Negative Log Liklihood

I utilized the "png mnist dataset" just to make sure my network can handle multiple input channels and is why the input is an rgb sized image which I standardized to 0 to 1. Hyperparameters:
-Batch Size = 128
-Initial Learning rate = 0.002
-Optimizer = RMS-prop
Has anyone else had a similar issue training this type of network on the MNIST or know why the network cannot learn past 60%? I saw this same network architecture being used in a keras tutorial with the exception of the average pooling layer being a max pooling layer.

Hi @MceBab, welcome to the site. Please, show training and validation loss curves. Also, why a single convolutional layer?

I figured out the issue. For anyone else making a numpy network, take note since I only saw one other post on this issue.  You cannot just save the output of training sample and then average the Error across all these outputs to solve the gradients. Instead save the gradient for each layer after each sample is forward propogated. Average these gradients after you run your batch you in order to update.
